# How to play picturebox gif animation correctly while doing background operation?

Tags: c#, .net, animation, backgroundworker, picturebox

Hi I have a windows form application.I am reading NFC card then writing the data to the card. After writing operation, I am sending the data to the WCF service. While writing and then sending data, I want to show a gif in a picturebox. But gif animation doesn't work. Altertanively, I move the writing and sending operation to the backgroundworker in order not to block working gif animation, but I could not get a result to solve problem.
How can I overcome the problem ? Is there another aternative way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I had the same problem. I use a background worker to do a lengthy DB search, and show a picturebox with a gif animation before the bg operation starts. But the gif did not play (it played when I put it in a picturebox without the background operation). I had set the gif as a background picture (for easy centering). When I set it as a regular image (using the Image property) it did play. So apparently gifs as background image are treated differently from gifs as 'regular' images.